# How have I managed to start two netcat servers on the same port?

Tags: linux, networking

```
dewi@dewiserver:~/code/dot-files/vpn$ s | grep  8889
tcp               LISTEN                 0                   1                                                                                          0.0.0.0:8889                                               0.0.0.0:*                     users:(("nc",pid=2997375,fd=3)) uid:1000 ino:40683621 sk:890 <->
tcp               LISTEN                 0                   1                                                                                          0.0.0.0:8889                                               0.0.0.0:*                     users:(("nc",pid=2997227,fd=3)) uid:1000 ino:40677127 sk:891 <->
dewi@dewiserver:~/code/dot-files/vpn$
```

I don't quite get what is going on. How was I permitted to start a process that listens to an inuse port?
thanks

Comment: It uses SO_REUSEPORT

Comment: @AlexD i learn something new every day. Thanks :)

Comment: The source of your `s` might help to help.